# Disable ADuser if the user still has the check change password at next logon

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm doing user audits, and I'm assigning the check change password at next logon.
After xxx time I run script to remove the check and disable the accounts that still have the check and export these users.
I'm trying this way and it's not working for me.

```
    Get-ADuser -LDAPfilter "(pwdLastSet=0)" | select SamAccountName |

Out-File -FilePath .\users.txt -Append

$users = get-content .\users.txt
foreach ($Row in $users) {
    if(Get-ADUser -LDAPfilter "(sAMAccountName=$($Row.username))"){
        Set-ADUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -Identity $Row.username
        Set-ADUser -Enabled $false -Identity $Row.username -Description "User Disabled after xxxxx days"
    }
}
```

Someone knows a way to do that and can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is at **$Row.username**.

**$Row** is not a hash table and has no properties. Therefore **$Row.Username** would equal nothing.

```
Get-ADuser -LDAPfilter "(pwdLastSet=0)" | select SamAccountName | Out-File -FilePath .\users.txt -Force

get-content .\users.txt | %{
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -Enabled $false -Description "User Disabled after xxxxx days"
}
```